# python how to find all word matches between two text files

Tags: python, string, file

I have two text files comprised of around 370k words each, one word per line. One of the files is a list of English words and the other is a list of random gibberish words. I basically want to check if any of the random words are in fact real words, so I want to compare every line in one file with every line in the other file.

I've tried the following:

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
for line in f1:
    if line in f2:
        print(line)
```

and this gives me about 3 results before the program inexplicably ends without an error.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It ends because you read to the end of f2 the first time you run the outer loop.

Comment: @nicomp how can I skip back to the beginning of f2 each loop?

Comment: open and close `f2` inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what i understood you want the `intersection` of both lists, you can try this:

```py
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

print(set(f1.readlines()).intersection(f2.readlines()))

f1.close()
f2.close()
```